# rxswift receiving last element before disposing

Tags: swift, observable, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have an `observable` that will get disposed after some time. What i want is to get the last element before the observable is disposed. I have been trying but i am unable to find an operator for this purpose.

The `onDisposed` completion handler doesn't have anything as a parameter and going through the docs i cannot find any other operator for this purpose.

```
selectedObservable
            .subscribe(onNext: { isSelected in
                //Do something
            }onDisposed:{
               //Somehow get the last emitted element
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: This requirement seems smelly to me... What is the problem you are trying to solve by getting the last element before disposal?

Answer (score 0):

You need the takeLast operator. Also, you are allowed to subscribe to an observable more than once and in fact it's expected. Many beginners forget about this ability:

```
selectedObservable
    .subscribe(onNext: { isSelected in
        // do something
    })

selectedObservable
    .takeLast(1)
    .subscribe(onNext: { lastSelected in
        // this is the last value emitted
    })
```